# Unable to initialise ObjectMapper in micronaut library subproject

Tags: kotlin, aws-lambda, micronaut, jackson-databind, micronaut-aws

I have multi-project setup in which there are following subprojects:

- common
- data
- domain
- utility

The projects are build using gradle and coded in Kotlin

All of the above projects are defined as micronaut libraries.

`data` depends upon `common`

`domain` depends upon `data`

`utility` depends `domain`

The utility project is build to generate a JAR which is then deployed on AWS Lambda java runtime

Below is the `build.gradle.kts` file for the utility project

```
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.8.21"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.allopen") version "1.8.21"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt") version "1.8.21"
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "7.1.2"
    id("io.micronaut.library") version "3.7.10"
}

group = "com.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

val kotlinVersion = project.properties["kotlinVersion"]

dependencies {

    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${kotlinVersion}")
    implementation("jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api")

    implementation("io.micronaut.kotlin:micronaut-kotlin-runtime")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-jackson-databind")

    implementation("io.micronaut.crac:micronaut-crac")

    // AWS Runtime specific
    implementation("io.micronaut.aws:micronaut-function-aws")

    implementation(project(":domain"))

    runtimeOnly("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.4.8")
}


java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("17")
}

tasks {
    compileKotlin {
        compilerOptions {
            jvmTarget.set(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.JvmTarget.JVM_17)
        }
    }
    compileTestKotlin {
        compilerOptions {
            jvmTarget.set(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.JvmTarget.JVM_17)
        }
    }
}

micronaut {
    runtime("lambda_java")
    testRuntime("junit5")
    processing {
        incremental(true)
        annotations("com.example.*")
    }
}
```

In the above kotlin version is 1.8.21 and micronaut version is 3.10.0

Inside the domain sub-project, there is a service class which has the following line of code

```
@Inject
lateinit var objectMapper: ObjectMapper
```

When the code runs the objectMapper instance is not injected here and the code fails with the error

```
lateinit property objectMapper has not been initialized: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException
```

When the same line of code is written in a class of the utility project as a property of a `MicronautRequestHandler` type class. It works without any issue.

What might be the problem here? Why can't I inject objectMapper instance in the domain subproject but it works in the utility project?

Comment: @RoarS.Sure that can be considered at some point but that does not necessarily help me resolve my issue